# tokenize two times a csv file

Tags: c, csv, tokenize, strtok

I'm using strtok() in C to parse a csv string.

My example string is:

```
str= "name1 secondname1 cin,name2 secondname2 cin"
```

I first use strtok with the delimiter "," and second I delimit the string with " ".

```
char delims1[] = ",";
char delims2[] = " ";
char *result1 = NULL;
char *result2 = NULL;

result1 = strtok(str, delims1);

while ( result1 != NULL ) {

    result2 = strtok(result1,delims2);

    while ( result2 != NULL ) {
        printf("%s\n" ,result2);

    }

    result1 = strtok(NULL, delims1);
}
```

The result expected is:

```
name1
secondname1 
cin
name2
secondname2
cin
```

Comment: What are `str` and `divided` and what do they contain?  You need to show that code.  Also, what results are you actually getting?  You don't state what your question is.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: What a beautiful demonstration of the problems with `strtok()`.  It's a bad function to use almost always; the list of its faults is manifold, but in particular, you cannot have two concurrent sets of splitting going on as you seem to want.  If you must try, use `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` (POSIX vs Windows, roughly).  You're missing the call to `strtok()` in the inner `while` loop, so since nothing changes `result2`, the code goes into a permanent loop. While `strtok()` or its family can be made to work for the sample data, it cannot sensibly used for general CSV data parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  When you ask a question, try to actually *ask a question*.

In this case, however, I'll just assume that you are not getting the expected output.

The problem is that `strtok` stores internally the state of your last call.  So if you mix two different parses then you will run into trouble.

The Microsoft implementation of the C library provides `strtok_s` which allows you to pass the state variable in.  If you are using that compiler, then switch to using that function.  Otherwise you may need to write your own.

Alternatively, you can tokenise each column in one pass and store the pointers in an array.  Then do a second pass and tokenise each string in the array.

Comment: Among the several problems with this code is that he doesn't show how `str` and `divided` are initialized.  These are two separate strings and we don't know what they contain.  The most serious problem is that the second `while` loop will be an infinite loop if `result2` is not null.

Comment: That's true, but reading between the lines it's clear that there is a second call to `strtok` setting up a new parse inside the loop.  Assuming that the user gets their program running or posts all relevant code, this is the root of current or future problems.  Given the title, they seem to suspect something is wrong with doing that, so I am clarifying that their suspicions are correct. =)

Comment: see also strtok_r().  @paddy It hasn't been my experience that "Reading between the lines" is a good approach with SO questions.  Sometimes the code really is just as bad as you might fear.